# For Loop plotting zero in matplotlib [Python]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginner at Python and I'm trying plot a cos function which is inside a matrix. But it's plotting zero values once in a while

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eigh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=np.zeros((2,int(10/0.01)))
   for i in range(2):
      for time in np.arange(0,10.01,0.01):
          coll=int(time/0.01)-1
          A[i,coll]=np.cos(time)
plt.plot(A[0])
```

[image: The Plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your intent correctly, you wish to create a 2x1000 matrix with each row representing a hundredth of a (time) unit between 0 and 10 units (inclusive), and then apply the cosine function to each element. Correct?

Following the inner for loop one can immediately see that the matrix indexing is being offset and is not going linearly from 0 to 10. Consider the first iteration:

```
int(0/0.01) - 1 # This evaluates to -1, and, as a column index, points to the last element
```

However this shouldn't really be making all those zeros you see, as it would only create "wrong" values at the ends of the interval and create a tiny offset in the graph. Nevertheless, this is something to take note of.

A little investigation into the values (just employing print-function-debugging, really) reveals a deeper problem: some of the elements are not updated at all!

The first zero occurs during iteration 29 (index 28)

```
row 0, col 26, time 0.27, elem 0.9637708963658905
row 0, col 27, time 0.28, elem 0.9610554383107709
row 0, col 27, time 0.29, elem 0.9582438755126972
```

Notice anything weird?

Yes, Python rounds `int(0.29/0.01)` to `28`, because `0.29/0.01` evaluates to 28-point-something due to weird rounding issues about which one must be ever careful, and `int()` truncates that to 28. So, essentially, wherever you see a zero in the final matrix, the previous entry in the row was updated twice.

## The Numpy-esque way to do it

As someone new to Numpy, the temptation to stick with Python's for loop is understandable, but the effective way to use the library is to take advantage of its vectorised operations, which are usually faster in performance and also easier to read. With exposure and practice, these should become second nature. (You can look these methods up in Numpy's documentation for other details and examples.)

To achieve the same result using Numpy's in-built methods, try this:

```
# array of 1001 points
timeline = np.arange(0, 10.01, 0.01)
# Create matrix (2d-array) of identical rows by vertically stacking the timeline array
time_matrix = np.vstack((timeline, timeline))
# cos() applied to each element of the matrix
cos_times = np.cos(time_matrix)
plt.plot(timeline, cos_times[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works though:

```py
small = 1e-7

import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eigh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=np.zeros((2,int(10/0.01)))
   for i in range(2):
      for time in np.arange(0,10.01,0.01):
          coll=int((time + small)/0.01)-1
          A[i,coll]=np.cos(time)
plt.plot(A[0])
```